# XmlDocment - how to get nodes by filtering using XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

If you have an XML document and you need to find certain nodes based on certain attribute values (4 in number) which one would be the correct approach (in terms of performance):-

a) Filter the XML document (with `XPath`) to get node list which match any of the attribute values and then traverse through the filtered Node list to get nodes having a particular attribute value using If-else.

b) Filter the XML document (with `XPath`) for each attribute value separately.

```
<Nodes>
  <a class="myclass" type="type1">some text</a>
  <a class="myclass" type="type2">some text</a>
  <img src = "myGraphic.jpg?id={Guid}"/>
</Nodes>
```

I am using the below XPath (which might be incorrect :-))

```
"//A[@class] | //a[@class] | //IMG[@src] | //img[@src]"
```

The goal is to get the separate list of all a having type="type1" a separate list of type="type2" and a separate list of ids in the img tag.

Comment: Please show an example of what you mean. It's not clear why you wouldn't just use a single XPath expression to find all the nodes at once.

Comment: "why you wouldn't just use a single XPath expression" - This is a) option in the question. After getting all the nodes at once one needs to put If-else to get the node values for each type of attribute value. Is this a good approach. Added an example.

Comment: @user: take your time. It's not necessary for it to be a copy of your real XML. Just something that shows what you mean about the attribute values. For instance, I'm not getting why you need if/else.

Comment: John, added one example.

Comment: @user: ok, now which XML nodes do you want to match?

Answer (score 1):

My rough answer would be, performance is not going to really matter much unless you have a very large document or set of documents.

In that case, you probably will want to use SAX, and in any case, you'll want to traverse the document(s) only once, and not hold the whole thing in memory. So you'll be streaming through the documents, stopping at each `a` element, and appending it to list1 or list2 depending on its type.